# How do we understand if there is a image not found error?

Tags: image

I have a job to check some 300 urls if they are loaded correctly. They are the production urls of a company. One of the checks that we have to do is to understand if any of the image or the text not loaded properly.

For the images not loaded usually we get a cross mark.. But since we want to automate this task, what is the piece of code or the debugging tool which can tell us that there is 'image not found' error in a particular url?

We are also checking for error like '404' and '5xx' HTTP errors. But hoping to get the error if we check the debugging window.

Let me know in case more information is required.

Thanks
Dhanya

Comment: Surely "image not found" falls under the 404 category of "file not found", since an image is a file.  Unless you're serving them up via a script instead of files, in which case you'd want to look for results containing no data after the headers.

Comment: Hi Paddy, will check this out..